# Remove marker or Icon on google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used `setMap(null)` is not Working.

I Want How to Remove Marker in GoogleMaps V3

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function DeleteMarkers() { 
        if (markers.length > 0) { 
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
                var deleteMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: markers[i] }); 
                deleteMarker.setMap(null); 
            } 
            markers = []; 
         }
     }
```

Comment: where are you populating `markers`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new marker. Iterate and call setMap on the saved markers themselves.

```
function DeleteMarkers() { 
  if (markers.length > 0) { 
    for (var i = 0, overlay; overlay = markers[i]; i++) {
      overlay.setMap(null);
    }
  markers = []; 
  }
}
```